# Transparent opening at bottom of fixed element on mobile scroll

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

It's hard for me to explain this, but I currently have a fixed item at the bottom of the page, and it disappears once the user scrolls to the bottom of the site, showing another div with a large amount of text. Once the user starts scrolling back to the top of the site, the fixed element re-appears at the bottom of the screen. The position of the fixed element is set to "bottom:0".

Unfortunately, sometimes, when the user scrolls up there is a transparent box about 20px in height below the fixed item. You can see the elements on the page that would appear underneath the fixed element, but the fixed element stays on top.

When I click on this blank space, the Google search bar appears. Is the Google search bar the thing that is causing the transparent box below the fixed element? What else could it be? This does not happen on Developer tools emulators, only on actual phones.

Here is an image below:

[image: Picture of what I am experiencing]

Here is my JS:

```
$(".mobile-isi-expand").click( function (){
    var topMenuHeight = $('.mobile-top-menu').height();
    var documentHeight = $('#pageContent').height();
    var screenHeightSans = $(window).height();

    console.log(topMenuHeight);
    console.log(documentHeight);
    var desiredExpandedHeight = topMenuHeight;
    var desiredContractedHeight = "150px";
    var deviceHeight = $(window).height();
    var regionContent = $(".region-content").height();
    if(documentHeight === null){
        documentHeight = screenHeightSans;
    }
    else {

    }
        if($(this).hasClass("mobile-expanded")) {
            $(this).removeClass("mobile-expanded");
            $(".mobile-isi-container").animate({
                "height":"150px",
                "bottom":"0",
                "top":deviceHeight - 150
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("mobile-isi-minimize");
            $(".mobile-isi-expand").addClass("mobile-expanded");
            $(".mobile-isi-container").animate({
                "top":desiredExpandedHeight,
                "height": documentHeight
            });
        }
});


$(function($) {
    if(Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 480px)')) {
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            var is_root = location.pathname == "/";
            var referenceHeight = $('.referenceArea').height();
            var pageContentHeight = $("#pageContent").height();
            var regionContent = $(".region-content").height();
            var refAndPageHeight = referenceHeight + pageContentHeight;


            if($(this).scrollTop() >= regionContent - 220) {
                $('.mobile-hidden-isi').addClass("mobile-active");
                $('.mobile-isi-container').css({"display":"none", "height": "150px"});
            }
            else {
                $('.mobile-hidden-isi').removeClass("mobile-active");
                $('.mobile-isi-container').css({"display":"block", "height": "150px", "bottom" : "0"});
                var mobileISIheight = $('.mobile-isi-container').height();
                console.log(mobileISIheight);
            }
        })
       }
       else {

       }
});
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-isi-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: 'quicksandregular';
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    z-index: 999999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px -1px rgba(64,62,64,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px -1px rgba(64,62,64,1);
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px -1px rgba(64,62,64,1);
}
```

Comment: please share code and css of site on jsfiddle or codepen for better understanding and help.

Comment: I think it has to do with the height I am giging to "mobile-isi-container" in one of the functions I have which contract/expand the div.

Comment: Might be. But we have no way of checking this on mobile as no link to the website or jsfiddle etc. Can you provide link to the page which has this code and problem that we can check on our mobile and see what is the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I'd have to create a separate, fake page, which will take some time. If it comes to that, I will, otherwise thank's for the help.

Comment: Hi all, this occurred due to the address bar appearing and disappearing. It changes the calculated window.height(). All I did was add an overflow-y: visible instea of overflow-y: scroll in my css, and added a background color. This covers up the transparent area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this occurred due to the address bar appearing and disappearing. It changes the calculated window.height(). All I did was add an overflow-y: visible instea of overflow-y: scroll in my css, and added a background color. This covers up the transparent area, though it does make the height of the fixed element sort of variable.